# ANTS Profiler: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: red-gate-ants

I'm getting the error below during the "summarizing results" after stopping profiling a w3wp.exe process. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  at ??.?..?.?(Int32 profileeProcessID, Int32 millisecondsMax, Guid profilerClass, String profilerPath, IntPtr clientData, Int32 dataSize)
  at ??.?.??(Int32 , IEnumerable`1 )
  at ?.?.?()
```

Stack is

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
>   RedGate.Profiler.Engine.dll!..() + 0x1035 bytes 
    RedGate.Profiler.Engine.dll!..() + 0x2a3 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9b bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x4d bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permissions issue - w3wp inherits ANTS' permissions. Either log in with app pool account or change app pool to be able to run under your account.